# How to build AWS C++ SDK on Solaris?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, solaris

I am trying to build the AWS C++ SDK on Solaris, but I cannot do so successfully.

I found [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/743) open issue on the AWS C++ SDK page that says it is possible, but there is no guide on it and I am hoping somebody here can help.

Here is the command I use to build it:

```sh
$ cmake ../aws-sdk-cpp/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_ONLY="s3"
```

Here is the output:

```sh
-- TARGET_ARCH not specified; inferring host OS to be platform compilation target
-- Building AWS libraries as shared objects
-- Generating linux build config
-- Building project version: 1.7.134
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /workspace/dmoini/sdk_build/.deps
gmake: Warning: File 'Makefile' has modification time 267 s in the future
gmake[1]: Warning: File 'CMakeFiles/Makefile2' has modification time 267 s in the future
gmake[2]: Warning: File 'CMakeFiles/AwsCCommon.dir/progress.make' has modification time 267 s in the future
gmake[2]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
gmake[2]: Warning: File 'CMakeFiles/AwsCCommon.dir/progress.make' has modification time 267 s in the future
[  4%] Performing build step for 'AwsCCommon'
[  1%] Building C object CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/array_list.c.o
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:37:0,
                 from /workspace/dmoini/sdk_build/.deps/build/src/AwsCCommon/include/aws/common/common.h:22,
                 from /workspace/dmoini/sdk_build/.deps/build/src/AwsCCommon/include/aws/common/array_list.h:18,
                 from /workspace/dmoini/sdk_build/.deps/build/src/AwsCCommon/source/array_list.c:16:
/opt/gcc-5.1.0/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/5.1.0/include-fixed/sys/feature_tests.h:405:2: error: #error "Compiler or options invalid for pre-UNIX 03 X/Open applications        and pre-2001 POSIX applications"
 #error "Compiler or options invalid for pre-UNIX 03 X/Open applications \
  ^
gmake[5]: *** [CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/array_list.c.o] Error 1
gmake[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:484: CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[3]: *** [Makefile:139: all] Error 2
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/AwsCCommon.dir/build.make:112: build/src/AwsCCommon-stamp/AwsCCommon-build] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/AwsCCommon.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:193 (message):
  Failed to build third-party libraries.
```

Additionally, here is my system information:

```sh
$ uname -a
SunOS bld-dmoini-01-sv4b 5.11 omnios-r151020-4151d05 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

Any and all help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Solaris pretty strictly enforces POSIX standards for compiling code.  The code and/or makefile(s) likely have something like `#define _POSIX_SOURCE 1` incorrectly paired with something like `-std=c99`.  You'd have to post the exact compiler options being passed to `gcc` as well as the relevant contents of `/opt/gcc-5.1.0/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/5.1.0/include-fixed/sys/feature_tests.h` around line 405 for a more exact answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've successfully completed compiling the AWS C++ SDK on a stock install of Solaris 11.4, and found several issues that could cause the problems noted.

Start with a clean source tree.

**Remove `-Werror`**

The first thing do to is remove the `-Werror` compiler options.  The version of OpenSSL installed by default on Solaris 11.4 has quite a few deprecated functions, and the `-Werror` option causes the build to fail when it runs into those deprecations.  I used this `find` command run from the topmost directory of the AWS SDK source tree to remove all the `-Werror` options:

```
vi `find . | xargs grep -l Werror`
```

You'll get about three or four files, only two of which are actually setting the `-Werror` as a compiler option.  Just remove the `"-Werror"` strings from those files.

**Fix the POSIX defines**

Then run `cmake .` in the topmost directory.  It will fail because the cmake files that it downloads will have improper POSIX command-line options - `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500`.  That `500` is wrong.  `_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` corresponds to `_XOPEN_SOURCE=700`.  `_XOPEN_SOURCE=500` is [SUSv2, circa 1997](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification#1997:_Single_UNIX_Specification_version_2).  It's not proper to compile a SUSv2 application with C99.

Per [**2.2.1 Strictly Conforming POSIX Application**, paragraph 8](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html#tag_02_02_01):

> 8. For the C programming language, shall define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to be `200809L` before any header is included

and [**2.2.4 Strictly Conforming XSI Application**, paragraph 8](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html#tag_02_02_04):

> 8. For the C programming language, shall define `_XOPEN_SOURCE` to be `700` before any header is included

Per [the Illumos `sys/feature_tests.h` file](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/4e0c5eff9af325c80994e9527b7cb8b3a1ffd1d4/usr/src/uts/common/sys/feature_tests.h#L264) (based on OpenSolaris, which was also the basis for Solaris 11):

```
 * Feature Test Macro                                Specification
 * ------------------------------------------------  -------------
 * _XOPEN_SOURCE                                         XPG3
 * _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_VERSION = 4                   XPG4
 * _XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED = 1           XPG4v2
 * _XOPEN_SOURCE = 500                                   XPG5
 * _XOPEN_SOURCE = 600  (or POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L)      XPG6
 * _XOPEN_SOURCE = 700  (or POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L)      XPG7
```

The files `cmake` downloads via `git` need to be edited:

```
vi `find .deps | xargs grep -l XOPEN_SOURCE`
```

Change any `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500` to `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` and rerun `cmake .`.  It should complete successfully this time.

Then run `gmake`. (I find `gmake` works much better on Solaris for just about all open source projects, as many open source projects use GNU-specific `make` extensions.)

Now you get to fix any broken source code you run into.

**Fix broken source code**

**1**

The [file `aws-sdk-cpp/aws-cpp-sdk-core/source/platform/linux-shared/OSVersionInfo.cpp`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/797a5c5890e0c1772ac8de02cc6116d832dd7806/aws-cpp-sdk-core/source/platform/linux-shared/OSVersionInfo.cpp#L54) has the following wrong code:

```
Aws::String ComputeOSVersionString()
{
    utsname name;
    int32_t success = uname(&name);
```

[Per POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/uname.html), the correct type is `struct utsname`, not just `utsname`:

```
 int uname(struct utsname *name);
```

The AWS code needs to be:

```
Aws::String ComputeOSVersionString()
{
    struct utsname name;
    int success = uname(&name);
```

And no, I'm most certainly not impressed with the quality of the AWS code, given [this, umm, laugher](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/797a5c5890e0c1772ac8de02cc6116d832dd7806/aws-cpp-sdk-core/source/platform/linux-shared/OSVersionInfo.cpp#L37):

```
 while (!feof(outputStream))
```

Yes, an actual `while (!feof())` loop...

**2**

The file [aws-sdk-cpp/aws-cpp-sdk-mediaconvert/include/aws/mediaconvert/model/M2tsSegmentationMarkers.h](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/797a5c5890e0c1772ac8de02cc6116d832dd7806/aws-cpp-sdk-mediaconvert/include/aws/mediaconvert/model/M2tsSegmentationMarkers.h#L33) uses an enumeration with the value `EBP`, which conflicts with [the `EBP` register `#define` in `/usr/include/sys/regset.h`](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/4e0c5eff9af325c80994e9527b7cb8b3a1ffd1d4/usr/src/uts/intel/sys/regset.h#L108).

I just changed it to `EBP_HASH` as that seems to match the code somewhat:

```
vi `find . | xargs grep -l EBP`
```

**3**

The file [aws-sdk-cpp/aws-cpp-sdk-route53domains/include/aws/route53domains/model/CountryCode.h](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/797a5c5890e0c1772ac8de02cc6116d832dd7806/aws-cpp-sdk-route53domains/include/aws/route53domains/model/CountryCode.h#L92) creates an enumeration value `ES` that conflicts with [the `ES` register `#define` in `/usr/include/sys/regset.h`](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/4e0c5eff9af325c80994e9527b7cb8b3a1ffd1d4/usr/src/uts/intel/sys/regset.h#L112).  I just added

```
#ifdef ES
#undef ES
#endif
```

and the compile continued.  I don't know if that `#undef` could have broken anything.

**4**

The file [aws-sdk-cpp/aws-cpp-sdk-waf/include/aws/waf/model/GeoMatchConstraintValue.h](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/797a5c5890e0c1772ac8de02cc6116d832dd7806/aws-cpp-sdk-waf/include/aws/waf/model/GeoMatchConstraintValue.h#L235) has `ES`, `GS`, and `SS` enumeration value that conflict with [the `ES`, `GS`, and `SS` register `#define`'s in `/usr/include/sys/regset.h`](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/4e0c5eff9af325c80994e9527b7cb8b3a1ffd1d4/usr/src/uts/intel/sys/regset.h#L114).

Again, I just added a few more `#undef`'s:

```
#ifdef ES
#undef ES
#endif

#ifdef GS
#undef GS
#endif

#ifdef SS
#undef SS
#endif
```

I'm really wondering why `sys/regset.h` is being `#include`'d in just about everything in the AWS SDK.

**5**

Same problem in [aws-sdk-cpp/aws-cpp-sdk-waf-regional/include/aws/waf-regional/model/GeoMatchConstraintValue.h](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/797a5c5890e0c1772ac8de02cc6116d832dd7806/aws-cpp-sdk-waf-regional/include/aws/waf-regional/model/GeoMatchConstraintValue.h#L235).  Same fix, add:

```
#ifdef ES
#undef ES
#endif

#ifdef GS
#undef GS
#endif

#ifdef SS
#undef SS
#endif
```

Note that compiling on SPARC hardware means the `#define` value from `sys/regset.h` will be completely different, and any errors will be completely different.

**6**

The file [aws-sdk-cpp/aws-cpp-sdk-core-tests/utils/FileSystemUtilsTest.cpp](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/797a5c5890e0c1772ac8de02cc6116d832dd7806/aws-cpp-sdk-core-tests/utils/FileSystemUtilsTest.cpp#L284) incorrectly assumes the POSIX `NAME_MAX` value is defined.  Per [the POSIX **Pathname Variable Values** standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html#tag_13_23_03_02) (bolding mine):

> **Pathname Variable Values**
>
> The values in the following list may be constants within an
>   implementation or may vary from one pathname to another. For example,
>   file systems or directories may have different characteristics.
>
> A definition of one of the symbolic constants in the following list
>   **shall be omitted** from the `<limits.h>` header on specific
>   implementations where the corresponding value is equal to or greater
>   than the stated minimum, but where the value can vary depending on the
>   file to which it is applied. The actual value supported for a specific
>   pathname shall be provided by the `pathconf()` function.

Again:  the "definition ... **shall be omitted** ... where the value can vary".

The AWS code wrongly assumes `NAME_MAX` **must** be `#define`'d.

I just hardcoded a value of `255` to get past this point, although using something like `_POSIX_NAME_MAX` or `_XOPEN_NAME_MAX` is probably better.

**7**

File [aws-sdk-cpp/ws-cpp-sdk-core-tests/http/HttpClientTest.cpp](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/797a5c5890e0c1772ac8de02cc6116d832dd7806/aws-cpp-sdk-core-tests/http/HttpClientTest.cpp#L31) seems to be incorrectly assuming a `std::shared_ptr` will be 8 bytes.  [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082958/what-is-the-size-of-an-auto-ptr) provides a good example of how that's wrong.

I just ignored this error as it's just a test and continued with `gmake -i`, which completed successfully outside of this one error.